# How to construct endpoints with t.c.telnet

Tags: python, twisted, telnet

My goal is to create telnet clients as endpoints per the `TCP4ClientEndpoint` implementation.

Here's what Im doing:

```
class TelnetClient( TelnetProtocol ):
    ...

factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = TelnetClient
point = TCP4ClientEndpoint( reactor, x.x.x.x, 23 )
defer = point.connect( factory )

defer.addCallback( todo )
reactor.run
```

The `TelnetClient` class handles authentication, logging in, firing commands, etc.

when I use this approach, I can read some output off of `dataReceived`, but it's giberish.

The telnet client functions as expected when it is constructed by a `Factory` and then `reactor.connectTCP(...)` is called with the `Factory`.

What is it that Im doing wrong here?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**  connecting `TelnetClient` to `factory.protocol` via `TelnetProtocol`

```
class TelnetClient( TelnetProtocol ):
    ...

factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = TelnetTransport( TelnetClient )
point = TCP4ClientEndpoint( reactor, x.x.x.x, 23 )
defer = point.connect( factory )

defer.addCallback( todo )
reactor.run
```

**EDIT 2**  solved. The final piece was ClientFactory.

```
class TelnetClient( TelnetProtocol ):
    ...

factory = ClientFactory()
factory.protocol = TelnetTransport( TelnetClient )
point = TCP4ClientEndpoint( reactor, x.x.x.x, 23 )
defer = point.connect( factory )
```

Solving this problem was two fold.

1. Since we want a telnet client, we need to ensure that the protocol is an instance of `TelnetProtocol`.
2. The factory must be of `ClientFactory`.  If we look at the source of `twisted.internet.endoints`, we see that the factory we pass in to the endpoints is wrapped in `_WrappingFactory`, which is descended from `ClientFactory`. If this factory we pass in does not have the same attributes as `ClientFactory`, then the `_wrappedFactory` will cause AttributeErrors when it attempts to call methods of ClientFactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that`connectTCP` and `endpoint.connect` are functionally the same (for the most part).

Assuming that `TelnetProtocol` is `twisted.conch.telnet.TelnetProtocol`, the problem here is that `TelnetProtocol` is not really supposed to connect directly to a TCP transport, it's supposed to connect to a `twisted.conch.telnet.TelnetTransport`.  That "gibberish" in `dataReceived` that you're seeing are the actual telnet protocol bytes, which are supposed to be parsed by a `twisted.conch.telnet.TelnetTransport` (which is itself an `IProtocol`) in order to call methods like `enableLocal` and `enableRemote` on the `TelnetTransport`.

I would guess that in your `connectTCP`-based example, you are probably instantiating a `TelnetTransport` and setting *its* `.protocol` attribute to point at a `TelnetProtocol`.

Basically, make sure that the `Factory` object that you're passing in has *exactly* the same `protocol` attribute as the `ClientFactory` you're using in your `connectTCP` example.

In the future, also, please include complete, runnable code examples so that we can run them and see what happens rather than guessing :-).

Comment: Right, in the connectTCP version Im using TelnetTransport. Before I posted this question I tried implementing the same with the endpoint. Check out my edit. The problem there is that an AttributeError is raised saying Nonetype does not have connectionLost.  I havnt compare attributes as you suggest yet. My code is so hacked up right now,  Ill post an example that runs in the morning ( morning to me :) )

Comment: Problem solved on ensuring the Factory object has the same attributes as ClientFactory. Check out the edit.